# Only print matching lines in perl from the command line

Tags: perl

I'm trying to extract all ip addresses from a file. So far, I'm just using

```
cat foo.txt | perl -pe 's/.*?((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}).*/\1/'
```

but this also prints lines that don't contain a match. I can fix this by piping through grep, but this seems like it ought to be unnecessary, and could lead to errors if the regexes don't match up perfectly.

Is there a simpler way to accomplish this?

Comment: do you want to print lines or just ip addresses?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you've got grep, then just call grep directly:

```
grep -Po "(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}" foo.txt
```

Comment: I have to extract the ip address from a bunch of other text. It's not on a line by itself.

Comment: The grep command does that - it's the `o` switch: show only the part of a line matching PATTERN

Comment: **-P** Perl Regular Expressions (PCRE)
**-o** Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line

Comment: Important caveat: not all versions of grep support `-P`. The version that OSX ships with, specifically, broke -P some time in 2013.

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
cat foo.txt | perl -ne 'print if s/.*?((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}).*/\1/'
```

or:

```
<foo.txt perl -ne 'print if s/.*?((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}).*/\1/'
```

It's the shortest alternative I can think of while still using Perl.

However this way might be more correct:

```
<foo.txt perl -ne 'if (/((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/) { print $1 . "\n" }'
```

Comment: Can confirm the first incantation works, and is great for operating on single string variables by using `echo -n "$somevar"` before the pipe.

Comment: `<foo.txt perl` is awesome! i always used `cat foo.txt | perl` or `perl <foo.txt` ...

Answer (score 14):

You've already got a suitable answer of using grep to extract the IP addresses, but just to explain why you were seeing non-matches being printed:

`perldoc perlrun` will tell you about all the options you can pass Perl on the command line.

Quoting from it:

```
-p   causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it 
     iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed:

     LINE:
     while (<>) {
         ...             # your program goes here
     } continue {
         print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
     }
```

You could have used the `-n` switch instead, which does similar, but does not automatically print, for example:

```
cat foo.txt | perl -ne '/((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/ and print $1'
```

Also, there's no need to use `cat`; Perl will open and read the filenames you give it, so you could say e.g.:

```
perl -ne '/((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/ and print $1' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ruby -0777 -ne 'puts $_.scan(/((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/)' file
```